# Apache not finding index.php by default, set rule for routing through index.php

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, routing

Apache on the server is set to find index.php by default, and that works for a normal folder.

However, I have a `.htaccess` rule to route all requests through my routing script:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

With these .htaccess contents, the server returns a 404 error. Only by specifying `/index.php` does the routing script get called.

Any tips on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not allowing `.htaccess` files to be used.  You need a `<Directory>` stanza that contains:

```
AllowOverride All
```

The option All may not be best for your environment, so take a look at [this documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) to see what overrides you will allow in `.htaccess`.